# Detect ellipse parameters from a given elliptical mask

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I'm following the [tutorial from the skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html) website to detect edges from a mask and then get the ellipse perimeters.

[image]

However, when I run this code I get this:

[image: this]

I've reduced the threshold in the `hough_ellipse` function to 100 because that's the highest value that's working (which at times doesn't work with other masks) and `min_size` to 10 (for the same reason). I have no experience with with image processing or computer vision and have not found any other way to get the perimeters from large number of masks.

Comment: You have an image with a single ellipse. Why would you use anything complex such as the Hough transform to find it? It's already detected. There's nothing there except the ellipse!

Comment: Get the contour and use cv2.fitEllipe. That will return the ellipse center, major and minor diameters and the rotation angle of the ellipse.

Comment: @CrisLuengo what I want are the perimeters of the ellipse from the image.

Comment: Use `cv.findContours()` in OpenCV, for example. Skimage doesn’t seem to have a similar function, but it will allow you to get the parameters of the ellipse, which you can then draw. Use [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=ellipse#skimage.measure.regionprops). It gives major and minor axis length, orientation and centroid, all parameters of the ellipse.

Comment: @fmw42 thank you that worked perfectly. Can you please put that here as your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do that with fitting to an ellipse in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Fit ellipse to shape
- Draw ellipse on input image
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('ellipse_shape.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 252, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# fit ellipse
# note: transpose needed to convert y,x points from numpy to x,y for opencv
points = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))
hull = cv2.convexHull(points)
((centx,centy), (width,height), angle) = cv2.fitEllipse(hull)
print("center x,y:",centx,centy)
print("diameters:",width,height)
print("orientation angle:",angle)

# draw ellipse on input image
result = img.copy()
cv2.ellipse(result, (int(centx),int(centy)), (int(width/2),int(height/2)), angle, 0, 360, (0,0,255), 2)

# show results
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('ellipse_shape_fitted.png', result)
```

Resulting ellipse:

[image]

Ellipse Data:

```
center x,y: 291.0881042480469 337.10638427734375
diameters: 176.3456573486328 207.72769165039062
orientation angle: 125.05526733398438
```

Answer (score 0):

From this tutorial and with this image I got this parameter:

```
accuracy=50

threshold=50

min_size=100

max_size=100
```

[Hough ellipse example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeOF2.png)

Comment: If you intended this to be an answer to the question at the top of this page then you will have to make the answering part more obvious.... You can [edit] to do that. Even if "this tutorial" were a link, this would not be considered an answer.